# Add a element from a list and a value from a dictionary in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this:

```
my_funct(*args,**kwargs):
    dict = {}
    for arg in args:
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            dict[key] = value + arg
    print(dict)
```

The example is:

```
my_funct(1,2,3,a=100,b=200,c=300)
```

But the output is :

```
{'a':103,'b':203,'c':303}
```

And I want to get this output:

```
{'a':101,'b':202,'c':303}
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should answer your question:

```
def my_funct(*args,**kwargs):
    return {k: v+i for (k, v), i in zip(kwargs.items(), args)}
```

Please note this will only work correctly on Python 3.6+ due to it preserving the order of insertion in dicts.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through a,b,c 3 times and each time overwriting them with the latest value, you need to iterate over everything only once

This works if len(args) == len(kwargs)

```
dict = {}
for arg, (key, value) in (args, kwargs.items()):
  dict[key] = value + arg
```

Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
dict = {}
for key, value in kwargs:
  dict[key] = value
for i, key in enumerate(dict):
  if len(args)>i:
    dict[key] += args[i]
```